# Ansible - how to evaluate role_path variable

Tags: path, ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to evaluate the value of the `role_path` variable in order to use it in other roles as a reference point. The problem is, however, when my variable is used in another role, it has the value of the other role, and not of when it was declared.

I am getting around this by using an `echo` command of the current variable's value and registering the output as per below.

```
- name: get ansible base path from current role_path
  command: echo {{ role_path }}/../../
  register: ansible_base_path_out

- name: save ansible base path variable for future use
  set_fact:
    ansible_base_path: "{{ ansible_base_path_out.stdout }}"
```

Is this the best way to do this or is there a more eloquent solution?

Comment: @techraf - the variable is `role_path`, not `roles_path`. There is no 's' at the end of the word role. Whereas `roles_path` gives a list, `role_path` only gives the current role's path.

Comment: @techraf I beg to differ - whereas `roles_path` gives a list, `role_path` only gives the current role's path.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "how to improve a working code"-questions are off-topic on StackOverflow and should instead be posted on Code Review SE

Comment: @techraf my expectation is that instead of calling `command` and `set_fact` that this could be done with a single `set_fact` possibly with a jinja function to evaluate the variable.

Comment: lucky it wasn't closed, @techraf - I just got a gold medal for it! :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can safely use `set_fact`. Variables (fact) assigned via `set_fact` are evaluated during task execution time. Shrink your code to only one task:

```
- name: save ansible base path variable for future use
  set_fact:
    ansible_base_path: "{{ role_path }}/../../"
```

Apply this role at first and you'll get `ansible_base_path` fact unchanged throughout entire playbook execution.

Comment: Can you have a colon delimited path (with multiple role paths)? I have subrepos with roles

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `role_path` is the current role’s pathname.